# Better solution than if-else if?

Tags: c, embedded

I have to do some things based on the value of a big number like 83025 (which is >65535). For this I can't use switch-case since it uses only integral arguments of a max value of 255. (Or at least this is how I know. I still tried however and it compiled but the switch-case did not work well.)

So I thought I would make an `if-else if` ladder like this below but it seems not too elegant.

```
if      ((refnum == 32120) ||  
         (refnum == 32075))   {

else if  (refnum == 51036)    {

else if ((refnum == 61024) ||  
         (refnum == 61060))   {

else if ((refnum == 71030) ||  
         (refnum == 71048))   {

else if ((refnum == 72012) ||  
         (refnum == 72024) ||  
         (refnum == 72048))   {

else if ((refnum == 81025) ||  
         (refnum == 81050) ||  
         (refnum == 81100))   {

else if ((refnum == 82012) ||  
         (refnum == 82024) ||  
         (refnum == 82048) ||  
         (refnum == 82096))   {

else if ((refnum == 83050) ||  
         (refnum == 83100))   {
```

Can you confirm that this is the proper way to do this? Or do you have a better idea?

Additional info:

- refnum is a 32bit unsigned integer
- the big number comes from the middle of a string and `strtol` converts it to a DWORD
- the things i have to do in each case is to perform a `strcpy` and then `return` a certain value.
- the code is embedded and runs on a 16 bit microcontroller

Comment: Use a `switch` statement.  You can combine the shared cases.  They can handle any int.

Comment: do the case actions relate with refnum?

Comment: switch cases for only 8 bit ints? That's new to me. This would be very specific behavior of your compiler. Usually you can at least use the full range of use `int` (if not any enumerable).

Comment: What is the range of possible values of `refnum`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/5r143L6.png

Comment: According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch): condition - any expression of integral or enumeration type, ...; case constant_expression - a constant expression of the same type as the type of condition

Comment: @Scheff This is embedded C, not C++. Are they the same in terms of `switch` ?

Comment: @melpomene Done ;)

Comment: @Bathsheba Currently the biggest required number is 83100, but I don't know a theoretical maximum. But I suppose it's not bigger than a 32bit number :)

Comment: @TahaPaksu Of course they are related but not in algorithmical way. These reference numbers are unique identifiers of real world products.

Comment: @TomKarzes No, it seems switch can't handle **any** int. That's why is turned to if-else.

Comment: @Greenberet, show us two cases with full code.

Comment: And please tag your question with the name of the weird compiler that you are using.

Comment: @Greenberet Huh, that's really weird.  Sounds like you're dealing with a subset of C.  If the values form sufficiently dense clusters, it might be possible to do a few range checks, then adjust the values for switch statements with values in the range that works, e.g. `if (x >= 10000 && x <= 10255) switch(x - 10000) {}`  Or you could just use the `if-else` tree that you have - whichever seems to work best.

Comment: @melpomene deserves the "Comment of the Year" award for 2017.

Comment: Your problem is that your switch did not work, so you tried to solve the problem with if-else-if and then asked us about that - a classic X-Y problem.  Why not show us the switch code and let us suggest a solution.  A restriction to 8 bit values would be unusual, so what target/compiler are you using?  If that is truly a restriction of your compiler, then what you have coded is valid, so what is your question?

Comment: @melpomene As our companies security policy blocks imgur.com I had to use my private phone to have look. But, it was worth the effort...

Comment: @Greenberet I cannot imagine that C and C++ behave differently concerning the accepted types of condition expressions. I tried to google but couldn't find anything authoritative. If you're compiler doesn't support anything else except 8 bit ints then it's not a standard C compiler (what might be a fact). Btw. I would consider to sort the if-else cascades to form a binary search. The same applies to the alternative approach with the mapping table. (I assume that `switch` might be compiled in a similar way if the case constants are not dense enough for direct indexing.)

Comment: I just realized that the answer of chqrlie provided the info I wasn't able to find...

Answer (score 7):

> have to do some things based on the value of a big number like 83025

Then make sure that all variables involved use `uint32_t`.

> For this I can't use switch-case since it uses only integral arguments of a max value of 255

This is a misunderstanding, not sure where you got this idea from. The `switch` statement works on all integer constant expressions. There's no numerical limits in the switch statement itself.

(In fact the controlling expression of a switch statement is implicitly promoted to type `int`, if it happens to be a smaller integer type.)

> So I thought I would make an if-else if ladder like this below but it seems not too elegant. Can you confirm that this is the proper way to do this? Or do you have a better idea?

The if-else will likley yield the very same machine code as a corresponding switch. The switch might increase readability a bit and is therefore perhaps a better choice:

```
switch (refnum)
{
  case 32120: do_this(); break;
  case 61024: do_that(); break;
  ...
  default:    do_something();
}
```

---

Alternative:

I notice that these are integer values in sorted order. If there are lots of values or if fast look-up is required, you could also replace the whole thing with a binary search. This will possibly give faster code but also increase complexity. Preferably, use C standard `bsearch()`.

However, if what you wish to achieve in the end is to return a pointer to a string, this solution might be ideal. You could then store the numbers and strings as key-value pairs:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t key;
  const char* str;
} thingie_t;

static const thingie_t things [] = 
{
  { 32120, "text string" },
  { 32075, "another text string" },
  ...
};
```

---

> the big number comes from the middle of a string and strtol converts it to a DWORD

Why are you using signed numbers? The data does not seem to be signed. What is `DWORD`? That's some smelly type from Windows programming, which should definitely be avoided in embedded systems. Use the types from stdint.h, not some ugly, home-made types.

Answer (score 4):

> *I have to do some things based on the value of a big number like 83025 (which is >65535). For this I can't use switch-case since it uses only integral arguments of a max value of 255. (Or at least this is how I know).*

Your understanding is incorrect: here is the wording of the C Standard:

> **6.8.4.2 The `switch` statement**
>
> The controlling expression of a switch statement shall have integer type.
>
> [...] The expression of each `case` label shall be an integer constant expression and no two of the `case` constant expressions in the same `switch` statement shall have the same value after conversion. [...]
>
> The integer promotions are performed on the controlling expression. The constant expression in each `case` label is converted to the promoted type of the controlling expression. If a converted value matches that of the promoted controlling expression, control jumps to the statement following the matched `case` label. [...]

Thus there is no limit at `65535` for the case values in general, the maximum value is at least `18446744073709551615` if the `switch` expression has type `unsigned long long`. If your `switch` expression is an `unsigned int` and your target platform had 16-bit ints, then the maximum value for a case expression would be `65535` but given the values you want to test, `refnum`'s type must be a larger than that.

> *I still tried however and it compiled but the switch-case did not work well.*

You did not post the offending code... Unless your compiler is ancient or seriously broken, the problem is not where you suspect, more likely a bug in your code.

**EDIT** from the extra information provided, the target platform indeed has 16-bit `int`, but `refnum` must be larger than `int` or `unsigned int` to accommodate for values larger than `65535`, either a `long` or an `unsigned long`. The compiler should then accept `case` values larger than `65535`. Ancient compilers may not be compliant with this... in this case, you will probably have many more problems to deal with.

Comment: Thanks chqrlie, really! I will thoroughly think on all these!

Answer (score 3):

Switch statement can do the job for you in this case.

```
switch (refnum) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
        //Do stuff when refnum is 0 or 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //Do stuff when refnum is 2
        break;
    case 36371:
    case 36372:
    case 36373:
    case 36374:
        // if (refnum == 36371 || refnum == 36372 || refnum == 36373 || refnum == 36374)
        break;
    default: break;
}
```

Beauty is that you can apply multiple case statements (like `case 0` and `case 1` in my case) which acts like `or` in your if statement.

GCC extension also allows you to write your switch this way:

```
switch (refnum) {
     case 36371 ... 36374:
        //Do the job when refnum is >= 36371 && refnum <= 36374
        break;
}
```

But remember! This is not available in all compilers.

Comment: I think you didn't get my point. My problem is that `switch` doesn't work with variables this big...

Comment: @Greenberet what?

Comment: The GCC version should be avoided since it results in the same machine code as the standard one anyway. Programmer laziness is not a valid rationale for writing non-standard code.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a very restrictive non-standard compiler.

You could create a function for each action then generate a lookup-table of refnum to function-pointer and scan that.  For example:

```
int action1( unsigned long refnum ) ;
int action2( unsigned long refnum ) ;
int action3( unsigned long refnum ) ;
int action4( unsigned long refnum ) ;
int action5( unsigned long refnum ) ;
...
int action8( (unsigned long ) ;


int doRefnumAction( unsigned long refnum )
{
    typedef void(*refnumFn)(unsigned long ) ;

    static const struct 
    {
        unsigned long refnum,
        refnumFn refnum_action
    } refnum_lookup[] = { {32120, action1}, {32075, action1},
                          {51036, action2},
                          ...
                          {82012, action7}, {82024, action7}, {82048, action7}, {82096, , action7},
                          {83050, action8}, {83100, action8} } ;

    // Find refnum in lookup and call action...
    for( int i = 0 ; 
         i < sizeof(refnum_lookup) / sizeof(*refnum_lookup) ;
         i++ )
    {
        if( refnum == refnum_lookup[i].refnum )
        {
            return refnum_lookup[i].refnum_action( refnum ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Whether that is *better* in any way that the `if-else if` solution is perhaps a matter of opinion, probably larger in code-space terms, and slower in execution but arguably more easily maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Once we know details of your compiler and your real code, we can find out why you feel you cannot use a switch statement.  Until then, everyone is just guessing.

I have used a large number of C compilers over the years, and never heard of one that restricts switches in this way.  It sounds like the kind of pseudo-C compilers that existed for 8-bit microcontrollers in the 1990's - not something you would see today.

If you are using a decent compiler, and have optimisation enabled, then a switch will be the fastest way.  Someone mentioned binary searches as a more complex but faster solution - a good compiler will generate a jump table or a binary search automatically from a switch statement to give you the most efficient code.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a global array with all your values to check. And simply loop trought this array. If you need a specific behavior for each else if you could create an array of struct and use function pointer to set a different behavior.

Here's an example :

```
// For int variables
#include <stdint.h>
// For printf
#include <stdio.h>

#define VALUE_TO_GUESS 3
#define NB_VALUES 4
#define MY_VALUE_1 1
#define MY_VALUE_2 2
#define MY_VALUE_3 3
#define MY_VALUE_4 4

void behavior_1(void) {
  printf("Behavior 1 !\n");
}

void behavior_2(void) {
  printf("Behavior 2 !\n");
}

void behavior_3(void) {
  printf("Behavior 3 !\n");
}

void behavior_4(void) {
  printf("Behavior 4 !\n");
}

// Definition of the struct using a function pointer
typedef struct s_compare {
    uint32_t value_to_compare;
    void (*ptr)(void);
}t_compare;

// Setting up my struct
t_compare g_compare[] = {
    {MY_VALUE_1, behavior_1},
    {MY_VALUE_2, behavior_2},
    {MY_VALUE_3, behavior_3},
    {MY_VALUE_4, behavior_4}
};

int main(void) {

  for (int i = 0; i < NB_VALUES; i++) {
      /* If your current value match the value set in the current struct
      then call the function pointer associated, with these 2 lines i can 
      compare an infinite quantity of numbers  */
      if (g_compare[i].value_to_compare == VALUE_TO_GUESS) {
          g_compare[i].ptr();
      }
  }
}
```

Feel free to tell me if you need some explanations about this one.
This need a bit of setup but its a powerful solution to your problem and a more elegant solution than a tree of if / else / else if.

Comment: `uint32_t for_padding;` Eeh? What's that supposed to be? Struct padding is handled by the compiler, not by the programmer.

Comment: Its a good practice when you create a struct, always have a padded struct. This let the control to the user over the memory.

Comment: @ClerisseLucas No, it doesn't. The compiler can still insert additional padding.

Comment: @melpomene I've edited the post so maybe someone will evaluate my answer intead of basics details.